# How to add mask to loss function in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

My PyTorch `model` outputs two images: `op` and `psuedo-op`and I wish to backpropagate at only those pixels where `loss(op_i,gt_i)<loss(psuedo-op_i,gt_i)`, where `i` is used to index pixels. Clearly, `loss(op,gt).backward()` cannot achieve this. So how to do?

Have some rough solution in mind as follows:

```
def loss(pred, target):
       """ shape of pred/target is BatchxChannelxHeightxWidth, where Channel=1 """
        
        abs_diff = torch.abs(target - pred)
        l1_loss = abs_diff.mean(1, True)

        return l1_loss

o1 = loss(op,gt)
o2 = loss(psuedo-op,gt)
o = torch.cat((o1,o2),dim=1)

value, idx = torch.min(o,dim=1)

NOW SOMEHOW USE IDX TO GENERATE MASK AND SELECTIVE BACKPROPAGATION
```

Any other solution would also work if it allows me to backpropagate on `o1` but for only those pixels where `o1<o2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `relu` function for this purpose I think. Since you need to backprop only on `o1`, you first need to `detach` the loss `o2`. And there is also a minus sign to correct the sign of the gradient.

```
# This diff is 0 when o1 > o2, equal to o2-o1 otherwise
o_diff = nn.functional.relu(o2.detach()-o1)
# gradient of (-relu(b-x)) is 0 if b-x < 0, 1 otherwise
(-o_diff).sum().backward()
```

Here, using the `relu` as a kind of conditional on the sign of `o2-o1` makes it very easy to to void gradients for coefficients with minus sign

I need to emphasize that since `o2` is detached from the graph it is a constant with respect to your network, so it does not affect the gradient and thus this operation achieves what you need : it is basically backpropagating `d/dx(-relu(b-o1(x))` which is 0 if `b < o1(x)` and `d/dx(o1(x))` otherwise (where `b = o2` is constant).

Comment: This does not address my question. Here backpropagation is happening over the difference, which I do not want. I want to backpropagate on o1 only but for only those pixels where o1<o2.

Comment: Fair enough, I think it should work for you now, I added a `detach` and a sign "trick"